# Burp Suite の Proxy を Firefox に設定しても「接続を拒否されました」となってしまう

Tags: firefox, proxy

Burp Suiteを使うためにFirefoxのプロキシ設定などを済ませ、環境を作ることには成功したはずですが、FirefoxのProxyサーバーにBurp Suiteを設定し、何度Firefoxでどのようなサイトを開いても「Proxyサーバーへの接続を拒否されました」と表示されます、一体私はどの様にしたらこのエラーを解消できるのでしょうか。教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

Burp Suite 側で正常にプロキシが動作しているかも確認してみてください。

参考:
[BurpのProxyリスナーがアクティブか確認](https://burp-resources-ja.webappsec.jp/Documentation/burp/documentation/desktop/external-browser-config/check-listener.html)

Comment: はい、しっかりと動作しており、設定もできている模様です